# Call popup to create object when not found in import process

Tags: django, popup, django-import-export

I am using the django-import-export tool in order to import files. In some cases some foreign keys are not existing in the database yet and thus I get a DoesNotExist exception. So instead of creating the rows manually with the get_or_create function, I would like to call a popup window so that the user can fill the fields of the row.

Is is possible then to close the popup, store the values so that the import process would continue?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This question is too broad.  Try to actually do what you're saying and if you have an issue, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for how to ask a specific question.

Comment: Hello, I ve edited my question. Is it still too broad? Thank you for your response.